Instagram api response 400, no data is returned
I have created a short term token to grab instagram business account data from https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ with following permissions
pages_show_list
business_management
instagram_basic
pages_read_engagement
pages_read_user_content

and then i extend the short term token to longterm from https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/?access_token=SHORT_TERM_TOKEN=v21.0
But when i request instagram for grabbing media
curl -X GET "https://graph.instagram.com/me/media?fields=id,caption,children,permalink,media_type,media_url,username,thumbnail_url,timestamp&access_token=LONG_TERM_ACCESS_TOKEN"

It throws error

"Sorry, this content isn't available right now"

What am i missing?

Does the same request made directly in Graph API Explorer, using that same extended token, give you a different result? And if not, what result do you get when you use the short-term token instead?

The issue was that the token creator needed permissions for both the Facebook Page and the linked Instagram account. I resolved it by using Facebook Login and replacing /me/ in the URL with the Instagram account ID. This fixed the token for Instagram media queries. Just commenting incase someone comes across same issue. Thanks for your response.
